# Cannot remove Mozc input method

Tags: input-method

Today, I tried to switch input methods using Super+Space, and it landed on mozc with a grey "Mo" icon. I cannot remove this input method in Text Entry Settings. Is there a fix for this bug?

Comment: If you think it's a bug, you are in the wrong place. ;) This place is for questions on how to use Ubuntu. Did you have ibus-mozc or fcitx-mozc installed and then removed the package before having removed the item in Text Entry?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to this:

First, install dconf-editor
    sudo apt install dconf-editor

Next, type `dconf-editor` in the alt+f2 popup

Finally, in `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources` remove the missing input method from `sources`.